# Image not found for the Ubuntu 14-04 Kernel 3.13.0-144.193

Tags: 14.04, server, linux-headers

2 weeks back I used the path: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release-20180404/

To download the Image: for 3.13.0-144.193. Now nothing is found the path.
Can anyone please update is the path moved/removed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use the latest version by going to *Parent Directory*.

Comment: Yes but the thing is we are doing a kernel upgrade to that specific version which i mentioned.

Comment: But if you downloaded the images two weeks ago, can't you just reuse it ?

Comment: actually, I downloaded only cloud image. I need the qcou2 image for ESXi depoloyment.